# GridSearchCV: performance metrics on a selected class [unbalanced data-set]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to run a grid search over parameter values optimised for a score (e.g. 'f1') on a selected class, rather than the default score for all the classes?

[Edit] The assumption is that such a grid search should return a set of parameters maximising a score (e.g. 'f1', 'accuracy', 'recall') only for a selected class, rather than the overall score across all classes. Such an approach seems to be useful e.g. for highly unbalanced data-sets, when attempting to construct a classifier that does a reasonable job on a class with a small number of instances.

An example of a GridSearchCV with a default scoring approach (here: 'f1' over all the classes):

```
from __future__ import print_function

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5],
                 'C': [1, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000]},
                {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 100, 500, 1000, 5000]}]

clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=4, scoring='f1', n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
print()
print(clf.best_estimator_)

y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

How to optimise parameters for a best performance on a selected class, or  incorporate a test of a range of class_weight in GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 6):

Scoring metrics that require additional parameters are not part of the pre-built scoring functions within grid search.

In this case, additional parameter required is to select the class for which scoring has to be done

You need to import `make_scorer` and `fbeta_score` from `sklearn.metrics`.

`make_scorer` converts metrics into callables that can be used for model evaluation

The F-beta score is the weighted harmonic mean of precision and recall, reaching its optimal value at 1 and its worst value at 0

Parameters for F-beta

beta: beta < 1 lends more weight to precision, while beta > 1 favors recall, beta -> 0 considers only precision, while beta -> inf only recall

pos_label: specifies the class for which scoring needs to be done (str or int, 1 by default)

Code example is as below

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, fbeta_score

f2_score = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2, pos_label=1)

clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=4, scoring=f2_score, n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll want to use the `scoring` parameter in `GridSearchCV()`. There are a handful of pre-built scoring functions you can reference via string (such as f1), the full list can be found here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values. Alternatively you can make your own custom scoring function with `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer`.

If that isn't enough detail for you post a reproducible example and we can plug this into some actual code.